# Passing * to node as command line argument results in list of files and folders

Tags: javascript, node.js

We are working on a JavaScript app which can be invoked via the command line. We pass in various arguments including a list of keys:

`node index.js key1,key2,key3`

We'd like to be able to specify the following:

`node index.js *`

Which means process all keys, however this doesn't result in `process.argv[2]` equaling `*`, instead it passes in all the files in the current directory!

When console logging process.argv I'd expect to get this:

```
[
  '/usr/local/bin/node',
  '/Users/me/the-application/index.js',
  '*'
]
```

But instead get this:

```
[
  '/usr/local/bin/node',
  '/Users/me/the-application/index.js',
  'index.js',
  'node_modules',
  'package.json',
  'readme.md'
]
```

I see what it's doing, I just don't understand why and if there's a non ugly way around it.

Our first thought was simply supply `all`, but there could, however unlikely, be a key named all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that if I think of `*` as a special character, and escape it with `\`, it works.

`node index.js \*` gets me what I want.

Answer (score 1):

How about `node index.js /*` ? That should work

Comment: It does! But it now begs the question, why are these equivalent? `node 1 2 3` and `node '1' '2' '3'`?

Comment: @AdrianLynch at least in Unix shells, `*` is special (amongst others) and gets expanded to all files and directories in the current directory. By escaping the character with single quotes, the shell is told not to perform that expansion and just pass in a `*` character (alternatively, it can be escaped by prefixing it with a backslash). The characters `1`, `2` and `3` are not special.

Comment: You changed your answer?